# Google Maps Flash - Polygon with Holes, Crossing the meridian

Tags: actionscript-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have a problem with creating an overlay with a polygon that contains
multiple polylines.

I want to create a polygon with holes cut out for certain countries (to show
which areas are off limits). I do this by creating a polygone with multiple
polylines.
The first polyline was created to cover the entire visible area of the map.

i started off with this:

To get around only spanning one region-180/180

```
    var outer:Array = [ new LatLng(90, -180),
                        new LatLng(90, 180),
                        new LatLng(-90, 180),
                        new LatLng(-90, -180),
                        new LatLng(90, -180)]

    donut = new Polygon([],
                                        new PolygonOptions({
                                            strokeStyle: new StrokeStyle({
                                                thickness: 0}),
                                            fillStyle: new FillStyle({
                                                color: 0x000000,
                                                alpha: 0.5})
                                            }));

    donut.setPolyline(0, outer)
    map.addOverlay(donut);
```

Obviously this has a problem with only spanning one lot of lat/lng. And when
zoomed out, this doesnt work. To get around this i tried getting the bounds
of the map, toSpan() and getNorth(),getSouth() and so on. These didnt return
a true span of the visible map - as it maxed out at 180/360.

My solution was to use fromViewportToLatLng() of the pixel points of the
map, and set the opt_nowrap to 'true'

```
    var pnw:LatLng = map.fromViewportToLatLng(new Point(0, 0), true)
    var pse:LatLng = map.fromViewportToLatLng(new Point(map.width, map.height),
    true)
```

This produced results similar to this

```
    Lat Lng North West (89.77386689378173, -614.3294000000001)
    LatLng South East  (-89.07253945829217, 370.0455999999999)
```

From here i can then correctly set the polyline (on map move and zoom
events) to cover the entire map, no matter how many spans of longitude
occur:

```
    outer = [
             new LatLng(pnw.lat(), pnw.lng(), true),
             new LatLng(pnw.lat(), pse.lng(), true),
             new LatLng(pse.lat(), pse.lng(), true),
             new LatLng(pse.lat(), pnw.lng(), true),    
             new LatLng(pnw.lat(), pnw.lng(), true)    
            ]
    donut.setPolyline(0, outer)
```

*So far so good. *
Now, i want to add the donut holes to my polygon, again adding polylines to
the donut polygon.

```
    private var australia:Array    = [
                                      new LatLng(-9.7716, 143.0241),
                                      new LatLng(-23.4610, 158.1852),
                                      new LatLng(-45.1338, 147.1549),
                                      new LatLng(-35.2615, 111.5153),
                                      new LatLng(-20.6921, 113.0094),
                                      new LatLng(-10.0746, 130.3239),
                                      new LatLng(-9.7716, 143.0241)
                                     ]

    private var nz:Array    = [
                               new LatLng(-33.5951, 165.8254),
                               new LatLng(-33.5951, 179.7341),
                               new LatLng(-48.3845, 179.7341),
                               new LatLng(-48.3845, 165.8254),
                               new LatLng(-33.5951, 165.8254)
                              ]                

    private var hawaii:Array    = [            
                                   new LatLng(21.8000, -160.4347),
                                   new LatLng(22.5477, -159.7975),
                                   new LatLng(21.4067, -156.3533),
                                   new LatLng(19.5336, -154.4197),
                                   new LatLng(18.6511, -155.6392),
                                   new LatLng(20.6633, -157.8639),
                                   new LatLng(21.8000, -160.4347)    
                                   ]

    donut.setPolyline(1, hawaii)
    donut.setPolyline(2, nz)
    donut.setPolyline(3, australia)
```

The problem lies when the meridian line is visible in the map viewport. This
problem is more evident when zommed in, as the donut hole polylines jump
from the visible viewport to the other side of a lat long span.

Sometimes the outer array doesnt even correctly render, causing the donut
polygon to essentialy invert (polygons over the countries, rather than
cutouts)

I realise this is a tough one to visualise. I have attached the .as + .fla
file in case anyone wants to test it out.

http://www.digital.leskiwis.com/maps/MapTest.zip

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to make a big polygon with holes cut out for Australia, nz, Hawaii,...? Your code for adding the polylines seems wrong to me. I'd start with the big square:

```
 var outer:Array = [ new LatLng(90, -180),
                        new LatLng(90, 180),
                        new LatLng(-90, 180),
                        new LatLng(-90, -180),
                        new LatLng(90, -180)]

    donut = new Polygon([outer],
    new PolygonOptions({
   strokeStyle: new StrokeStyle({
      thickness: 0}),
      fillStyle: new FillStyle({
      color: 0x000000,
      alpha: 0.5})
}));
```

Then add your holes

```
//define au, nz, hi
//...

//the 0th polyline is already the outer edge...
donut.setPolyline(1, hi);
donut.setPolyline(2, nz);
donut.setPolyline(3, au);
```

Now you dounut is a big rectangle with 3 holes.
Then add it to the map:

```
map.addOverlay(donut);
```

I've worked with lots of polygons that crossed hemispheres and meridians in Google Maps before, you don't have to mess with the viewport or zoom region or anything like that. As long as you're defining the polygon the way you think you are, GM will draw it correctly in any bounding rect (even if you are zoomed in so far that no edge of the polygon is visible).

The other thing I see is that the giant polygon you're making to cover the whole world is a little ambiguous: For example 90,-180 and 90,180 are the same point (the north pole) a line connecting those coordinates would have 0 length. Doing stuff at the poles is kinda effed in Mercator. Any possibility of cutting it off a 89° N? I think that would make your outer polygon more happy.